# ESLint error I can't figure out

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am using ESLint 1.1.0 to lint my javascript files.  I am getting an error for the "id-match" rule.  Here is the rule definition:

```
"id-match": [ 2, "^[a-z,$]+([A-Z][a-z]+)*$", { "properties": false } ]
```

The code it is complaining about is here:

```
var startDate = new Date();
```

The error message is:

> 32:25  error  Identifier 'Date' does not match the pattern
>   '^[a-z,$]+([A-Z][a-z]+)*$'                        id-match

I'm stumped.

Comment: The regexp says that the first character should be a - z, `,` or $ ...

Comment: The variable defined is startDate which is what the rule should be checking.  It follows the pattern.  Date is a javascript reserved word, I can't imagine ESLint would flag that.  The rule page leads me to believe this shouldn't be happening.

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/id-match.html

Comment: `Date` is not a reserved word in JS. The rule checks all identifiers, and `Date` in `new Date()`  doesn't follow the pattern. Your regex doesn't accept capital letters at the start of the input. A character set matches any one of the enclosed characters, `+` matches the preceding item one or more times. In your regexp the character set is "the preceding item", and that lacks the `A-Z` characters. Also I suppose that you don't want to accept identifiers starting with a comma.

Comment: I'll give you that reserved may not be the correct term.  However, if I it to 
var startDate = new date();
I get the following:
32:25  error  A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter                                    new-cap
  32:25  error  "date" is not defined                                                                          no-undef
The warning about the identifier goes away as well.  That leads me to believe that ESLint understands that to be a constructor call, as well as knowing what Date is and as such shouldn't be flagging it.

Comment: ESLint can find constructors as well as we all, they are functions called with `new` operator. I've pointed out the regexp from your code, which is causing troubles, why don't you just fix the regexp?

Comment: You seem to be missing the reason I asked this question.  This rule is preventing me from calling functions I don't have any control over naming.  I removed the comma from the regular expression so it is fixed.  I don't want to allow variable names to start with capital letters, which is what will happen with your suggestion.  Date is the constructor I am calling and as such I don't expect it to be flagged.  Case in point, if I change the variable name to StartDate I get an ESLint error on that line for the capital S, which is what I want to happen.

Comment: Maybe I'am, but you never asked anything like this in the OP, actually you haven't asked anything, only stated, that you're getting an error, and you're stumped ...

Comment: @Nick Feel free to log this as an issue on eslint repo. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues